# jsf selectOneMenu is not showing the selected bean

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm developing a primeface 3.5/jsf 2.0 application, After form submission the selected  values (which are updated to DB) are shown correctly in the xhtml page(textinput, radiobutton,etc), but the selectOnMenu is not showing the selected BEAN item:

The inputText value is shown normally:

```
<h:inputText id="nodossier" value="#{ficheDescControl.selectedFicheDesc.noDossier}" />
    `
```

using a SelectOneMenu, the selected bean "selectedSpecialite" is not shown

```
<h:selectOneMenu id ="specialiteSelect" value="#{ficheDescControl.selectedSpecialite}" converter="specialite"
                 required="true" requiredMessage="Specialite is mandatory field">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />                   
<f:selectItems value="#{ficheDescControl.allSpecsObjects}" var="specialite" itemLabel="#{specialite.nomspec}" itemValue="#{specialite}"/> 

</h:selectOneMenu>
```

using an outputLabel, the selected bean "selectedSpecialite" is  shown by his name correctly

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{ficheDescControl.selectedSpecialite.nomspec}">
```

In addition the controller has annotation: @ManagedBean, @SessionScoped, and the converter is working normally and the POJO is submitted to the DB.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Can you post your managed bean and converter?

Comment: Where is `selectedSpecialite` being initialized? And is your managedbean serializable? Otherwise, your selectOneMenu is simply failing validation/conversion